# how can i call a modal inside a js function without clicking on modal button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

how can i call a modal inside a js function without clicking on modal button?

```
if (email != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/email.php",
            data: 'email='+ email,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                //alert(result);
                if (result == 'true') {
                    $.ajax({
                     //do some thing
                   });
                }
                else {
                    $("#sendemail").modal('show');
                    // there is no button for modal
                    return false ;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

now in else case modal is not opening which is in another file.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close your success function with a curly brace.

```
if (email != "") {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/email.php",
        data: 'email='+ email,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            //alert(result);
            if (result == 'true') {
                $.ajax({
                 //do some thing
               });
            }
            else {
                $("#sendemail").modal('show');
                return false ;
            }
       } // no syntex error
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Jquery Trigger function, this helps to create custom evenHandler. Ideally in your case you can generate an event based on your email status by invoking a function that sends a click event to a object or an id containing modal. For references see examples on [Jquery: trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)